# How to set two or more paragraphs to use the same amount of vertical space?

Tags: tex-core, paragraphs, context, line-spacing, context-mkiv

Given several paragraphs in ConTeXt or plain TeX, how can I ensure that all paragraphs use the same amount of vertical space, by adding white space to the end, as the longest paragraph in the set? E.g.:

```
    This is a paragraph
with only two lines.
    This paragraph is a
little bit longer and it
has three lines.
    This is the longest
paragraph, as it has
a second, third, and
fourth line.
```

The above paragraphs would get added white space afterward, such that they all occupy the same amount of vertical space as the last paragraph, because it is longest, e.g.:

```
    This is a paragraph
with only two lines.


    This paragraph is a
little bit longer and it
has three lines.

    This is the longest
paragraph, as it has
a second, third, and
fourth line.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another ConTeXt based solution, but this one works in a single pass. It requires you to store the content in buffers, then measures all the buffers and sets the height to maximum height (not necessarily the height of the last paragraph).

```
\newdimen\maxbufferheight

\def\placebuffertomaximumheight[#1]%
    {\maxbufferheight\zeropoint
     \processcommalist[#1]\domeasurebuffermaxheight
     \processcommalist[#1]\doplacebuffertomaxheight}


\def\domeasurebuffermaxheight#1%
    {\setbox\scratchbox\vbox{\getbuffer[#1]}%
     \scratchdimen\ht\scratchbox
     \ifdim\scratchdimen>\maxbufferheight
        \maxbufferheight=\scratchdimen
     \fi}

\def\doplacebuffertomaxheight#1%
     {\ruledvbox to \maxbufferheight
        {\getbuffer[#1]}%
        \blank[none]} %change \blank[..] to \par to get regular inter-para space


\starttext
\startbuffer[one]
Single line
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[two]
\input tufte
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[three]
\input ward
\stopbuffer

\placebuffertomaximumheight[one,two,three]

\stoptext
```

Once you have the basic mechanism, it is straight-forward to wrap this around a macro.

```
\newcount\nofmeasuredparagraphs

\def\startparagraph
    {\increment\nofmeasuredparagraphs
     \grabbufferdata[measuredparagraph-\nofmeasuredparagraphs][startparagraph][stopparagraph]}

\def\stopparagraph{}

\def\startmeasuredparagraph
    {\nofmeasuredparagraphs\zeropoint}

\def\stopmeasuredparagraph
    {\maxbufferheight\zeropoint
    \dorecurse\nofmeasuredparagraphs
        {\domeasurebuffermaxheight{measuredparagraph-\recurselevel}}%
    \dorecurse\nofmeasuredparagraphs
        {\doplacebuffertomaxheight{measuredparagraph-\recurselevel}}}

\starttext
\startmeasuredparagraph
\startparagraph
Single line
\stopparagraph

\startparagraph
\input tufte
\stopparagraph

\startparagraph
\input ward
\stopparagraph
\stopmeasuredparagraph


\stoptext
```

This gives

[image]

I am using `\ruledvbox` so that you can see the box. Change that to `\vbox` if you don't want to see the box.

Comment: `\grabbufferdata` was introduced around Feb 2011. If you are using an older version add `\let\grabbufferdata=\dostartbuffer`.

Answer (score 7):

you can use

```
\vbox to 5cm{stuff.......\vfill}
```

To force a box of the right vertical size, padded with space at the end.

instead of 5cm you can measure one of the boxes first so

```
 \setbox0\vbox{longest stuff....}
```

then for each paragraph you can do

```
\vbox to \ht0{stuff.......\vfill}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here I provide a more ConTeXtish solution based on the same idea as Davids solution. It incorporates the now [two-pass data](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Key_Value_Assignments#Two-pass_data) mechanism.

```
\defineframedtext [normalparagraph]
  [
      frame=off,
     offset=overlay,
      width=\textwidth,
     height=\datasetvariable{lastparagraph}{last}{height},
  ]

\definedataset [lastparagraph]
\newbox\mylastbox

\definestartstop [lastparagraph]
  [
    before=\setups{last:before},
     after=\setups{last:after},
  ]

\startsetups last:before
  \setbox\mylastbox\vbox\bgroup
\stopsetups

\startsetups last:after
  \egroup
  \setdataset [lastparagraph] [last] [height=\the\ht\mylastbox]
  \box\mylastbox
\stopsetups

\starttext

  \startnormalparagraph
    \framed[align=normal]{\input knuth\par}
  \stopnormalparagraph

  \startnormalparagraph
    \framed[align=normal]{\input ward\par}
  \stopnormalparagraph

  \startlastparagraph
    \input knuth
  \stoplastparagraph

\stoptext
```

Result:

[image: result]

The `normalparagraph`s are simple `vbox`es with the height of the last paragraph. The `height` value is picked up from the two-pass data set. The `lastparagraph` is also a `vbox`, which height is measured and saved in the `.tuc` file. The `\framed` after `\starttext` are just added for illustration. Fill it with your content.