# Vertical distribution over multiple pages

Tags: vertical-alignment

I want to distribute several elements over multiple pages with a gap between these elements. The gaps should roughly have the same height.

Example:

```
element1

\vspace*{\fill}

element2

\vspace*{\fill}

element3

\vspace*{\fill}

element 4

\vspace*{\fill}
```

If only the first three elements fit on the first page, I get something like this,

```
+--------+    +--------+
|element1|    |element4|
|        |    |        |
|element2|    |        |
|        |    |        |
|element3|    |        |
|        |    |        |
+--------+    +--------+
```

but I want a distribution like this

```
+--------+    +--------+
|element1|    |element3|
|        |    |        |
|        |    |        |
|element2|    |element4|
|        |    |        |
|        |    |        |
+--------+    +--------+
```

Furthermore, I want the elements are always spread over an even number of pages.

The background of this question is the following: I would like to print out my digital calendar (*.ics) in a typical filofax-style with two pages per week. Each day should have some space for handwritten notes in order to add appointments, todos etc. I sometimes have more appointments at the beginning of the weeks, sometimes at the weekends, so a fixed pagebreak between Wednesday and Thursday wouldn't be a good solution. In very rare cases, a week doesn't even fit onto two pages, so it would be nice to automatically distribute the days over an even number of pages.

Is it at all possible to have something like a `\multipagevfill` or is TeX only able to focus on one page at once? Maybe with additional runs like supertabular?

Comment: If you're interested in a ConTeXt solution, have a look at the answers to the question [Creating a table which spans verso and recto pages in ConTeXt?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50307/5245)

Comment: I never used ConTeXt, so I would prefer a solution in LaTeX. I would try it in ConTeXt if this is the only option to this problem, but unfortunately the answers of the mentioned question don't fit here. Maybe I haven't described the problem not clearly enough. I don't want to align element2 and element4, I want to have _roughly_ the same amount of vertical space between each element.

Pseudo Algorithm
1. Determine the minimum number of pages for all elements (pages mod 2=0)
2. Arrange the pagebreaks in a way that the standard deviation of the heights of the gaps is minimal (= _roughly_ equal)

Comment: The task is not fully described, IMHO. Minimal (even) number of pages is always two (for up to 100 elements), because the minimum of gaps can be zero. Is it your concept?

Answer (score 1):

You can define `tcolorboxes` with certain `text height` (or `height fill` to completely fill the available space). `text height` will fix box height in independence of box contents, so you can complete box contents with handwritten text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Monday, text height=5cm]
\begin{itemize}
\item Task
\item Task
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Tuesday, text height=5cm]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Wednesday, height fill]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will suffice, since I can't try it under your actual conditions.  But I created a macro

```
\PageElements[<min element vertical size>]{<no pages>}{<no elements>}
```

by which one sets up the desired number of pages and elements one wishes to distribute.  That macro merely defines a `\mingap` which is later applied (along with a `\vfil`) after each element.

The optional argument may be needed in some situations, but defaults to 0pt.

In the MWE below, I distribute 4 elements across 2 pages, then 6 elements across 2 pages, and finally 6 elements across 3 pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\element[1]{\leavevmode\framebox(100,100){element#1}\vgap}
\def\mingap{0pt}
\newcommand\vgap{\leavevmode\vspace{\mingap}\vfil\par}
\newcommand\PagesElements[3][0pt]{\def\mingap{%
  \the\dimexpr\textheight/\numexpr#3/#2+1\relax-\dimexpr#1\relax}}
\begin{document}
\PagesElements{2}{4}
\element1
\element2
\element3
\element4
\clearpage

\PagesElements[40pt]{2}{6}
\element1
\element2
\element3
\element4
\element5
\element6
\clearpage

\PagesElements{3}{6}
\element1
\element2
\element3
\element4
\element5
\element6
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Page 1

[image]

All 7 pages

[image]